# Your Amazon Music marketplace is not configured correctly for this device

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to test my audio sample, but getting error like '**Your Amazon Music marketplace is not configured correctly for this device.UnsupportedAmazonMarketplaceMusic.PlayMusicIntenten_USdefaultf84533a2-71d6-44fa-810d-8969cb3863d01Adm-20170712_094208-34UnsupportedAmazonMarketplaceMusic.PlayMusicIntent{}Your Amazon Music marketplace is not configured correctly for this device**'

Here is my code for that Intent,

```
var audioFile='<audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-test-bucket/1-Can+you+train+like+a+pro+AND+keep+your+job.mp3"/>'
    this.emit('ask:','Hello. ${audioFile}' ,'How is this audio?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your region. If you google this you would find an answer right away on Amazon. Maybe your Lambda server should also be in the same region your amazon market place is.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201420320